# ENV variable inaccessible (null) in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, .env

Getting the following error when I access my Laravel app from the browser
[image]

A portion of the `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I have tried running the following commands

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Every command I run results in the same error

[image]

I have also tried deleting and creating a new `.env` file.

Comment: The error message isn't saying that the env variable is empty, it is saying `$settings` is null or `(int)$settings` makes it a non-object I guess. Please post code and errors as text so it can be copy&pasted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That was stupid of me.

Answer (score 3):

The null coalescing operator (??) does not work the same on objects as it works on arrays. While this works fine if $settings does not have a "smtp_port" key

```php
$settings['smtp_port'] ?? env('MAIL_PORT')
```

for objects you need to do something like this:

```php
$settings?->smtp_port ?? env('MAIL_PORT')
```

either way 2 things to keep in mind:

- as a rule of thumb, only **cast the resulting operation**, rather than each part individually

  ex: `(int)($settings?->smtp_port ?? env('MAIL_PORT'))`
- don't use `env()` outside of config files since the environment variables will **NOT** be loaded if the config is cached.

Comment: Perhaps also good to mention that `(int) $settings?->smtp_port ?? env('MAIL_PORT')` will result in `0` when `$settings` is `null`, and that `env('MAIL_PORT')` would result in `null` because of configuration caching.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the error message and was trying to fix `.env` which was stupid of me.

Answer (score 2):

## Understanding the issue

```
<?php

$settings = null;

echo $settings->smtp_host ?? 'abc';
```

**Output:**

> abc

And now let's consider this one:

```
<?php

$settings = null;

echo (int)$settings->smtp_host ?? 'abc';
```

**Output:**

> PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "smtp_host" on null in /foo.php on line 5

So, we can say with certainty that:

- `$settings` is `null`
- `$settings->smtp_host ?? 'abc'` does not error out despite the fact that `$settings` is `null` and, instead falls back to abc
- `(int)$settings->smtp_host ?? 'abc'` errors out because in order to evaluate `(int)$settings->smtp_host` the evaluation of `$settings->smtp_host` is a necessity and since `$settings` is `null`, it errors out despite the fact that you have a `??`, because you basically force the reaching of a field of a `null` variable

## Technical solution for such evaluations

If `$settings` is `null`, that means it was uninitialized and you need to initialize it and then you will need to ensure the fields:

```
<?php

// Dummy env function, use yours instead
function env($what) {
    switch ($what) {
        case 'MAIL_HOST': return '127.0.0.1';
        case 'MAIL_PORT': return '80';
        case 'MAIL_ENCRYPTION': return 'someencryption';
        case 'MAIL_USERNAME': return 'foo';
        case 'MAIL_PASSWORD': return 'bar';
        default: return null;
    }
}
// Mapping between smtp field names and env keys
$mapping = [
    'smtp_host' => 'MAIL_HOST',
    'smtp_port' => 'MAIL_PORT',
    'smtp_encryption' => 'MAIL_ENCRYPTION',
    'smtp_username' => 'MAIL_USERNAME',
    'smtp_password' => 'MAIL_PASSWORD'
];
//Initializing $settings if it was not initialized
if (!isset($settings)) {
    $settings = new StdClass();
}
// Looping our mapping and setting whatever was missing from $settings
foreach ($mapping as $field => $key) {
    if (!isset($settings->{$field})) $settings->{$field} = env($key);
}

//Converting smtp_port to int
$settings->smtp_port = (int)$settings->smtp_port;
```

Now, let's build your array:

```
$someArray = ['transport' => 'smtp'];
foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {
    $someArray[$key] = $value;
}
```

and you can assign `$someArray` as the value of your `'smtp'` field.